# Java stream elegant solution to avoid looping multiple times

Tags: java, java-stream

```
class Note{
    private text;
    ..
    private int score = 0;
}

class Project{
    ...
    List<Note> notes;
    private int score = 0;
}
```

Project score is derived by project properties + sum of note scores.

First I'm updating and replacing all notes in the project. Then iterating again to sum the note score.

```
 project.notes(project.notes()
        .stream()
        .map(this::updateNote)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

 project.score(project.notes()
                .stream()
                .mapToInt(n->n.score())
                .sum());

private Note updateNote(Note note){
    note.score(....);
    return note;
}
```

Somehow I feel this is not right. Is there an elegant solution to avoid looping twice?

Comment: If you don't plan to parallelize the stream then `.peek()` might be one way to go after `.map()` which can save you from reiterating it twice but the tradeoff is a side effect.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat, `peek` should be used mainly for debugging purposes, otherwise is _abuse_ :)

Comment: @AlexRudenko The whole idea of side effects in functional programming is absurd but it applies to one who doesn't know what he is doing. Java is an OOP by design and the notion of functional programming is just an abstraction over it. So in this case, since there is no short-circuiting terminal operation and given that we are mutating an `AtomicInteger` won't have any problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing a side-effect-ful method in a map operation like this is suspect no matter how you want to slice this puzzle, it's always going to look a bit weird.

You're abusing map here: You map objects to itself, but in so doing, cause a side effect. well, in for a penny, in for a pound, I guess - *that* is the suspect thing here, but the code works (it's just bad style). Note also that passing the collected list to `project.notes` **does nothing**, just `project.notes().stream().map(this::updateNote).collect(Collectors.toList())` and letting the collection be lost to the either already 'works'. The only point of collecting is merely to force the stream to actually iterate (map doesn't cause iteration, it merely says: When you start iterating, map as-you-go).

So:

```
project.notes()
  .stream()
  .map(this::updateNote)) // no-op streamwise. Just making the side effect happen
  .mapToInt(this::score)
  .sum();
```

is all you need - but it's.. still a bit stinky. If instead of `updateNote`, note was immutable and there is a `calculateScore` method, you could do:

```
project.notes()
    .stream()
    .mapToInt(this::calculateScore)
    .sum()
```

Here, `calculateScore` doesn't change anything about a `Note` object, it merely.. calculates the score and returns it, without changing any fields.

EDIT: I forgot a 'stream' in stream, and added a clarification.

Comment: yes the code was bad. Thanks for clearing more than what's asked for.

Comment: But calculateScore updating Note object stinks as well.

Comment: @sreehari I edited the answer: added a clarification and fixed a bug in one of the snippets

Comment: I actually need to change Note score as well for listing Notes sorted. So I believe your first option is suitable here.

Comment: @sreehari I'd strongly consider ditching stream() entirely for this and writing a plain jane foreach loop instead, then. You kinda create a presumption of immutability here; the option you went with is bad code style.

Answer (score 1):

You may get rid of looping twice by accumulating the sum in an `AtomicInteger`, but this would result in replacing the method reference `this::updateNote` with a lambda:

```java
AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);

project.notes(project.notes()
        .stream()
        .map(note -> {
            Note updated = updateNote(note);
            sum.addAndGet(updated.getScore());
            return updated;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

project.score(sum.intValue());
```

Comment: Curious! Why the `AtomicInteger` ? `stream` executes sequentially.

Comment: Excuse me, don't quite understand your question.  `AtomicInteger` needs to be used (other workarounds as an array or static variable are possible) because we update some state _outside_ the stream, while the external variable used in the stream must be [effectively final](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-effectively-final-local-variables).

Comment: Yeah, right makes sense. I was just wondering the atomic part.